# What is groovy-all-1.x-2.x.x.jar in Gradle Wrapper dists/gradle-6.x-all/<hash>/gradle-6.x/lib dir?

Tags: groovy, gradlew

When I use my IntelliJ IDEA to lookup the sources of some Groovy methods in build.gradle I end up disassembling classes from the JAR file in the title.

When I look into the JAR it's not a groovy-all distribution of let's say version 2.x.x.

Is **userhome/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.x-all/somehash/gradle-6.x/lib/groovy-all-1.x-2.x.x.jar** a blend of 1.x and 2.x.x groovy-all distributions used by Gradle in some way?

Comment: "Is it a blend of 1.x and 2.x.x groovy-all distributions used by Gradle in some way?" - There should be many jar files under the directory you mentioned.  Which one one in particular are you asking about?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, by it I meant the exact jar from the title - groovy-all-1.x-2.x.x.jar .
I'll edit the question to make it more clear.